# Tinymce editor get content of only 5 columns of a table

Tags: tinymce, bootstrap-modal, q, tinymce-plugins

```js
var myTableArray = [];
var numberOfColumns = 5;
    
    $("#previewDiv").html(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
    //console.log(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
    $("#previewDiv").find("table tr").each(function(){
        var arrayOfThisRow = [];
        var tableData = $(this).find("td");
        if (tableData.length > 0) {
            if(tableData.length < 5){
                numberOfColumns = tableData.length;
                
            }
            for (var i=0; i< numberOfColumns; i++){
                arrayOfThisRow.push(tableData[i].innerHTML);
            }
            if(tableData.length < 5){
                for(var j = numberOfColumns; j<5; j++){
                    arrayOfThisRow.push("");
                }
            }
            myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);

            /*if(tableData.length < 5){
                numberOfColumns = tableData.length;
            }
            for(var i=0; i< numberOfColumns; i++){
                
                arrayOfThisRow.push(tableData[i].$(this).text());
            }
            if(arrayOfThisRow.length < 5){
                for(i= numberOfColumns; i< 5; i++){
                    arrayOfThisRow.push("");
                }

            }
            //console.log(arrayOfThisRow);
            myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);*/
        }

    });
```

**Q.** I am getting an html table of variable column numbers and I want to parse only 5 columns out of it

**Background info:**
I have set a default content in the text area of tinymce editor. This default content is a table with 5 columns and no restriction on the number of rows.

I parse the content in this editor text area to a bootstrap modal pop-up, which displays exactly the same content as in text area of tinymce editor.

Whenever, a user copies more than 5 columns of table content and paste it in the textarea of tinymce editor, the parsing breaks and the excess of 5 column values are returned as "undefined" in the modal pop-up.

How do I restrict the getcontent() method of tinymce to only parse 5 table columns of the table and disregard the other columns if the user pastes more than 5 table columns.

Also, please let me know if there is a way I can share my code, which will help you understand better. Please see the attached images
[tinymce editor pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8mCX.jpg)
[modal pop-up pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmTBC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The API `getContent()` does exactly what it says it will do - its gets the entire contents of the editor.  If you need a subset of that content you would need to parse out what you need.

If you don't want people adding more columns why not use `contenteditable` to stop people from adding more columns to your table?

Comment: I cannot control user's behavior to add table of more than 5 columns, I would like to know how should i write the parsing function so that my function only prints the first 5 columns of the table? Please find my current parsing function code attached